# How to create custom Delete/Destroy button/command in Kendo UI grid?

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI grid with `GridEditMode.InCell` and I need to add a hyperlink for delete/destroy command in the grid column instead of the default "Delete" button.

My current code looks like:

```
c.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(90);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is what I end up doing

```
          c.Template(@<text></text>)
              .Width(50)
              .ClientTemplate(@"<a class=""k-button-icontext k-grid-delete"" href=""\#"">Delete</a>");
```

Comment: Yeah um this provides me with the markup defined above but clicking on it does nothing.

Comment: Note that you have to add the .Editable() onto the grid for the event to be attached to a "k-grid-delete" item

Comment: `@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Your.Type>() ... .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))`  There are 2 types of GridEditModes.  My link includes a span for the icon: `<a class=""k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-delete"" href=""\#""><span class=""k-icon k-i-delete""></span>Delete</a>`

Answer (score 13):

All you need to do is to add an element which has the `k-grid-delete` class.

For example you can add the following anchor element into a template column and it will start working as a delete button.

```
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-delete" href="#">My delete !</a>
```

Comment: Thanks XMR for you response.  However I don't understand where should I add that code.  c.Command doesn't have template or ClientTemplate, so I can't add it there.  I also tried:
                      c.Bound(p => p.Id)
                          .ClientTemplate("<a href='#' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-delete'>My delete !</a>")
                          .Title("Action")
                          .Width(100);
Please advise.

Comment: Indeed I suggested you to add it to the ClientTemplate. Isn't it displayed when you use the ClientTemplate? Or it does not work when you click the button.

Comment: Thanks again.  ClientTemplate is not method of the Command.  So when I apply it, code still compiles, but I am getting runtime error "CS1061: 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridActionColumnBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ClientTemplate' and no extension method 'ClientTemplate' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridActionColumnBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
Please advice.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Yes the Command column does not have a Template/ClientTemplate method - the above should be used on a regular Template column.

Comment: You pointed me  to a right direction +1, thanks a lot, but it was not exactly correct, you don't have to use k-button, since it still was creating the button.  I am going to post my full answer on this.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Petur,you are right we can add client template for that.But i want to know in case of adding client template to we can define datasource action method for destroy command ? I want to show custom delete confirmation message box for Destroy command.And for that if i use client template approach then how i can add the .Datasource method for it ?